# Typescript cannot resolve css locator shortcut ('$') dollar sign

Tags: typescript, protractor, typescript-typings

I am using protractor for some time and we are now migrating from js to typescript.
We are accustomed to use the shortcut for locators. For example:

```js
$('[test-id="generate2"]').click()
```

instead of:

```js
element(by.css('[test-id="generate2"]')).click()
```

As described in protractor documentation:
https://www.protractortest.org/#/locators
"When using CSS Selectors as a locator, you can use the shortcut $() notation:"

However, when trying to compile it in typescript I get the following error:
Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript:
error TS2592: Cannot find name '$'. Do you need to install type definitions for jQuery? Try `npm i @types/jquery` and then add `jquery` to the types field in your tsconfig.

well, it is not jquery so I won't try the above proposition.
However I did try both:

```
npm install @types/protractor
npm install @types/jasmine
```

but they didn't resolve my issues.

Any ideas about how to resolve?
10x

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you write protractor+typescript, you need to use import for that:

```
import {$} from 'protractor'
```

as well if you want to use other protractor global params:

```
import {$, $$, browser, ExpectedConditions as EC } from 'protractor'
```